# SQLite only return query execution time but not content

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to repeatedly run a query in sqlite saving results to a file. I've tried setting the following before the queries:

```
.timer ON
.echo OFF
```

But to no avail as results are still printed. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

`.echo` affects only commands, not their results.

To redirect the printing of results, use `.output`.